# How to install sqlite3 gem on EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, amazon-ec2

When I tried to:

```
 sudo yum install ruby-devel sqlite3-devel
```

Amazon EC2 returns:

```
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 Setting up Install Process
 Package ruby-devel-1.8.7.330-1.5.amzn1.i686 already installed and latest version
 No package sqlite3-devel available.
 Nothing to do
```

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

returns

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`sudo yum install sqlite3-devel` should be:

```
sudo yum install sqlite-devel
```

Answer (score 6):

On my Ubuntu box, I installed the following two libraries, plus the gem, in the following order:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install sqlite3  # this installs several tools, including the command-line utility
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby # this is going to spit out a bunch of errors, but you may be able to ignore them
```

Comment: Please see returns from `sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby` in question update.